# Alternate form assuming x is real?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can you help me to understand how the following transition happens:

$\frac{\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{x^4}}}{x} \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt {1+{x^4}}}{x^3} $

Wolfram Alpha says the right hand side is an alternate form assuming x is real.

For the context, I am working to understand how to calculate the surface of Gabriel's Horn. I am doing this via the phone app called Brilliant that simplifies the function to the following form:

$2π\int_1^b\frac{\sqrt {1+{x^4}}}{x^3}$, if we take b to $\infty$.

And I just can't figure out how to derive that from the original longer form, which I dont have energy to share here but I am able to simplify it to the left hand side version on the beginning. It has to also be correct because Wolphram Alpha recognizes that it can be turned into form I am looking form, "assuming x is real".

I might missing something really basic here, but can not figure out, please help me.

Comment: Just multiple denominator and numerator by $x^2$. Then, inside $\sqrt\{\}$, it become multiple by $x^4$

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by the same thing that will get you the form.  If the alternate form *is* correct, we must  multiply top and bottom by $x^2$ as that is the only thing that will transform $x$ into $x^3$.     

 
 If we do that we see $\frac {\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^4}}}x = \frac {x^2\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^4}}}{x^2\cdot x}=\frac {\sqrt{x^4}\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^4}}}{x^3} = \frac {\sqrt{x^4 + \frac {x^4}{x^4}}}{x^3} = \frac {\sqrt{x^4 + 1}}{x^3} = \frac {\sqrt{1+x^4}}{x^3}$ and it works.

Comment: Extending the comment of @AbelWong, if $f(x)$ is any well defined expression then $f(x) \times 1 = f(x).$  Further, for any **non-zero** real number $x$, you have that $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4}}{x^2} = 1.$$  So, all that happened is that an expression was multiplied by $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4}}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Don't worry *too* much about "if $x$ is real".  They just mean if $x$ is not real can't always assume $x^2 = \sqrt{x^4}$ is well defined or that $\sqrt{x^4}\sqrt{1 +\frac 1{x^4}}$ is actually equal to $\sqrt{x^4(1+\frac 1{x^4})}$.  We can't assume such assumptions with complex numbers but we can with real numbers.

Comment: Thank you all! This was much faster and more comprehensive than I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{ \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}}{x}=\frac{ \sqrt{\frac{x^4+1}{x^4}}}{x}=\frac{ \frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^2}}{x}= \frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^3}$

where the identity $\sqrt{x^4}=(x^4)^{1/2}=x^2$ is used.

Remark:

Assume $z=|z|(\cos \theta + j \sin \theta) \in \mathbb{C}$, then as a consequence of the De Moivre's theorem, the quantity $(z)^{1/n}$ is given by:

$(z)^{1/n}=|z|^{1/n}(\cos (\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n})+j\sin (\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n})), \qquad k=0,1,\dots,n-1$

Therefore in the field of complex numbers, the $n$-th root of a number gives $n$ distinct solutions. So, in your formula you would have $n=2$ solutions. However, since $x$ is real (and so $x^4$ is), you do not come across this fact.

Comment: Thank you, this answered well to the more explicit part of the question. The more implicit one, 'what does it mean when x is real in this context', was answered well in other comments.

Comment: I have added the explanation to your question in my previous answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, great! Thanks